# Query MySQL database for user names with their email addresses

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to query all of my users (simple enough) but i need to get specific users back in the results. I'll try explain the best i can below but in short i want to use a list of email addresses as a reference to pull all users matching those email addresses.

## Brief overview

I have a wordpress website which i run events from. When people sign up for the events an account is created for them. there is also another table for attendees which links these user profiles to their registrations.

As it is right now i need to get a list of people specific to one event organiser. I thought the best way to do this would be to use their email address from the attendee info and query my wp_users table for the user names.

```
SELECT display_name
FROM `mydatabase`.`wp_users` WHERE `user_email` LIKE 
'myemail@email.com' OR 
'mysecondemail@email.com' OR
'mythirdemail@email.com';
```

I've removed the real email and changed the database name.

What i am trying to achieve is a query that will run through my list of users comparing their email address that i provide to the users in the table and return any of them that match.

As it is right now it returns the first result it finds and stops.

I've got the list of emails ready to go but i am struggling to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the column name like this in the `where` clause

```
SELECT display_name
FROM `mydatabase`.`wp_users` 
WHERE `user_email` = 'myemail@email.com' 
   OR `user_email` = 'mysecondemail@email.com' 
   OR `user_email` = 'mythirdemail@email.com'
```

or use `IN()`

```
SELECT display_name
FROM `mydatabase`.`wp_users` 
WHERE `user_email` IN ('myemail@email.com', 'my2email@email.com', 'my3email@email.com')
```

And `like` is only used when searching with wildcards. For instance

```
where email like '%@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: Thanks Juergen. I have just tried both methods and both did exactly as i wanted. Thank you for your time. 

Is there any difference with regards to performance between the two solutions you posted?

Thanks for clarification on the LIKE clause. I thought it was the '%' that created the wild card when the LIKE clause was used. 

Much appreciated il add this to my OneNote.

PhilB

Comment: There is not difference in which one you use but one: When the `in` clause contains just one `null` value then the complete comparision returns `false`. So don't use `in` if you have `null` values in your column

Comment: That is worth noting as there could be some null values in my data. So you have probably saved me some time there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so i managed to figure this out a few minutes after posting this.

I didnt fix the initial issue but i managed to find and create a relationship between the two sets of data in Power BI and get the list i needed.

Thanks though.

PhilB

Comment: Hi, i thought it might be but if you could provide some insight into why then i would be happy to accept it as a solution!